# Fullcalendar with Vue without CLI

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I have a small Vue project that isn't in a build environment that is just a bunch of JS files and uses Vue from the CDN

I would like to use **FullCalendar** in my Vue project and ideally use the official FullCalendar Vue component, but this only seems to be available for projects using the CLI build environment.

Is there a Vue component available for non-build projects that I could use that still implements the normal `<FullCalendar />` tag?

Comment: Non-built project is a footgun. It's not necessary to use Vue CLI, it's only one of possible setups. But you need to use some build environment (Webpack or else) to use Vue in real world projects because a lot of third-party Vue libs don't provide bundles. You can do some leg work yourself for each lib that you need to use and see if it's prebuilt. FC is,  https://unpkg.com/browse/@fullcalendar/vue@5.8.0/dist/main.global.js

Answer (score 1):

About CDN [see](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
    });
    calendar.render();
  }    
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.8.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.8.0/main.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="app">
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would it be possible to have the calendar react to changes in the v-model in this scenario, say adding & editing events?

Comment: I think you are better off using **Vuetify Calendar** then, I modified the example slightly and added to the end of the answer as the snippet. [original example is here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/#day-body) In order to get any of the examples, open it in the sandbox, then export. You will find the result in the archive in the `dist` folder (`CDN` will be used), Good Luck!